# text editor-style renaming of filenames in directory

Tags: bash, regex, rename, filenames, batch-rename

How can I edit the names of files in a directory as though I were editing the text of a file using a text editor?

I feel like I've seen this demoed in a video, perhaps using some Vim plugin or another--or maybe it was in Sublime text?

I would like to be able to do regex string replacements, make arbitrary edits, etc, without having to write a shell script or draft an arcane shell command.

Comment: I don't have the answer to your exact question but the `rename` command in Linux is quite useful for many common batch rename cases.  You use it like `rename str_to_replace_from str_to_replace_to files_to_run_on_wildcards_are_supported`.

Comment: this isn't what you're looking for exactly.. but you can get all the filenamse in a file then use regexes to build your regex  commands.  so your list of filenames starts as file1; file2; file3;  becomes  mv file1 file1;  mov file2 file2; e.t.c.  which becomes  mv file1 fiiiile1.a;  mv file2 fiiiiile2.a; e.t.c. and you can make edits too.

Comment: or a custom program that when a key is released it or after x seconds, checks for any changes and renames files as you've done thme. Or it saves changes when you click update.

Comment: Have a look at [massren](https://github.com/laurent22/massren). It works with any text editor and, according to the author: _The tool works by creating a file that contains the filenames of the target directory, and opening this file in the text editor. You can then modify the filenames there directly. Once done, save the text file and the files will be renamed. Lines that are not changed will simply be ignored._

Answer (score 3):

You can look at [edir](https://github.com/bulletmark/edir), which lets you use any editor.

Answer (score 1):

On arch-linux, `vidir` is bundled as part of `moreutils`.

```
moreutils /usr/bin/vidir
```

After running `vidir` in the directory you are renaming the files, vim editor will auto-open.

Edit your file  - and saving the changes (`:wq`) - the filenames will be updated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

There’s always [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)’ [Dired](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired.html) mode.